# How to add the android view on top of html view but not full screen?

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am creating the app in ionic framework and I am calling the custom plugin which have the video player. Now my problem is Video player is opening in new window rather than current opening window. I want it to open on top of my Html page but not full screen only half screen. the final page will have html page on top of that In right side half page i want my plugin to open.any help how to do this thanks in advance.
this is my plugin

package cordova.plugin.VLCPlugin;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mindtree.gladiuscms.R;

import org.videolan.libvlc.EventHandler;
import org.videolan.libvlc.IVideoPlayer;
import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.Media;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaList;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import cordova.plugin.VLCPlugin.util.SystemUiHider;
import cordova.plugin.VLCPlugin.util.UrlProvider;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FullscreenVlcPlayer extends Activity implements  SurfaceHolder.Callback, IVideoPlayer {

    private  String              urlToStream;

    // Display Surface
    private LinearLayout        vlcContainer;
    private SurfaceView         mSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder       holder;

    // Overlay / Controls

    private FrameLayout         vlcOverlay;
    private ImageView           vlcButtonPlayPause;
    private Handler             handlerOverlay;
    private Runnable            runnableOverlay;
    private Handler             handlerSeekbar;
    private Runnable            runnableSeekbar;
    private SeekBar             vlcSeekbar;
    private TextView            vlcDuration;
    private TextView            overlayTitle;

    // media player
    private LibVLC              libvlc;
    private int                 mVideoWidth;
    private int                 mVideoHeight;
    private final static int    VideoSizeChanged = -1;
    private UrlProvider urlProvider = new UrlProvider();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retrieve our url
       // Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        UrlProvider urlProvider = UrlProvider.getInstance();
        urlToStream = urlProvider.getUrl();
        Log.d("Data url sdfjksdf", urlToStream);
//        urlToStream = "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";// b.getString("url", null);


        // HIDE THE ACTION BAR
//        getActionBar().hide();

        // SETUP THE UI
        try{
            getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_vlc_player);
            }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("TAG", "error");
        }

        // VLC
        vlcContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vlc_container);
        mSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.vlc_surface);


        // OVERLAY / CONTROLS
        vlcOverlay = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.vlc_overlay);
        vlcButtonPlayPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vlc_button_play_pause);
        vlcSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.vlc_seekbar);
        vlcDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vlc_duration);

        overlayTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vlc_overlay_title);
      //  overlayTitle.setText("rtsp://172.22.68.96:21212/Stream-2");

        // AUTOSTART
        playMovie();

    }


    private void showOverlay() {
        vlcOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void hideOverlay() {
        vlcOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void setupControls() {
        getActionBar().hide();
        // PLAY PAUSE
        vlcButtonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (libvlc.isPlaying()) {
                    libvlc.pause();
                   // vlcButtonPlayPause.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_play_over_video));
                } else {
                    libvlc.play();
                   // vlcButtonPlayPause.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_over_video));
                }
            }
        });

        // SEEKBAR
        handlerSeekbar = new Handler();
        runnableSeekbar = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (libvlc != null) {
                    long curTime = libvlc.getTime();
                    long totalTime = (long) (curTime / libvlc.getPosition());
                    int minutes = (int) (curTime / (60 * 1000));
                    int seconds = (int) ((curTime / 1000) % 60);
                    int endMinutes = (int) (totalTime / (60 * 1000));
                    int endSeconds = (int) ((totalTime / 1000) % 60);
                    String duration = String.format("%02d:%02d / %02d:%02d", minutes, seconds, endMinutes, endSeconds);
                    vlcSeekbar.setProgress((int) (libvlc.getPosition() * 100));
                    vlcDuration.setText(duration);
                }
                handlerSeekbar.postDelayed(runnableSeekbar, 1000);
            }
        };

        runnableSeekbar.run();
        vlcSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                Log.v("NEW POS", "pos is : " + i);
                //if (i != 0)
                //    libvlc.setPosition(((float) i / 100.0f));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        // OVERLAY
        handlerOverlay = new Handler();
        runnableOverlay = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                vlcOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toggleFullscreen(true);
            }
        };
        final long timeToDisappear = 3000;
        handlerOverlay.postDelayed(runnableOverlay, timeToDisappear);
        vlcContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                vlcOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                handlerOverlay.removeCallbacks(runnableOverlay);
                handlerOverlay.postDelayed(runnableOverlay, timeToDisappear);
            }
        });
    }

    public void playMovie() {
        if (libvlc != null && libvlc.isPlaying())
            return ;
        vlcContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder = mSurface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        createPlayer(urlToStream);
    }


    private void toggleFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
    {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
        if (fullscreen)
        {
            attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            vlcContainer.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
        else
        {
            attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }
        getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releasePlayer();
    }

    /**
     * **********
     * Surface
     * ***********
     */

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int format,
                               int width, int height) {
        if (libvlc != null)
            libvlc.attachSurface(surfaceholder.getSurface(), this);
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
    }

    private void setSize(int width, int height) {
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mVideoWidth * mVideoHeight <= 1)
            return;

        // get screen size
        int w = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
        int h = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();

        // getWindow().getDecorView() doesn't always take orientation into
        // account, we have to correct the values
        boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation      `**enter code here**`== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        if (w > h && isPortrait || w < h && !isPortrait) {
            int i = w;
            w = h;
            h = i;
        }

        float videoAR = (float) mVideoWidth / (float) mVideoHeight;
        float screenAR = (float) w / (float) h;

        if (screenAR < videoAR)
            h = (int) (w / videoAR);
        else
            w = (int) (h * videoAR);

        // force surface buffer size
        if (holder != null)
            holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);

        // set display size
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mSurface.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = w;
        lp.height = h;
        mSurface.setLayoutParams(lp);
        mSurface.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height, int visible_width,
                               int visible_height, int sar_num, int sar_den) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, VideoSizeChanged, width, height);
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * **********
     * Player
     * ***********
     */

    private void createPlayer(String media) {
        releasePlayer();
        setupControls();
        try {
            if (media.length() > 0) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, media, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,
                        0);
                toast.show();
            }

            // Create a new media player
            libvlc = LibVLC.getInstance();
            libvlc.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
            libvlc.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);
            libvlc.setSubtitlesEncoding("");
            libvlc.setAout(LibVLC.AOUT_OPENSLES);
            libvlc.setTimeStretching(true);
            libvlc.setChroma("RV32");
            libvlc.setVerboseMode(true);
            LibVLC.restart(this);
            EventHandler.getInstance().addHandler(mHandler);
            holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
            holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            MediaList list = libvlc.getMediaList();
            list.clear();
            list.add(new Media(libvlc, LibVLC.PathToURI(media)), false);
            libvlc.playIndex(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not create Vlc Player", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (handlerSeekbar != null && runnableSeekbar != null)
            handlerSeekbar.removeCallbacks(runnableSeekbar);
        EventHandler.getInstance().removeHandler(mHandler);
        if (libvlc == null)
            return;
        libvlc.stop();
        libvlc.detachSurface();
        holder = null;
        libvlc.closeAout();

        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
    }

    /**
     * **********
     * Events
     * ***********
     */

    private Handler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
        private WeakReference<FullscreenVlcPlayer> mOwner;

        public MyHandler(FullscreenVlcPlayer owner) {
            mOwner = new WeakReference<FullscreenVlcPlayer>(owner);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            FullscreenVlcPlayer player = mOwner.get();

            // Player events
            if (msg.what == VideoSizeChanged) {
                player.setSize(msg.arg1, msg.arg2);
                return;
            }

            // Libvlc events
            Bundle b = msg.getData();
            switch (b.getInt("event")) {
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerEndReached:
                    player.releasePlayer();
                    break;
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerPlaying:
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerPaused:
                case EventHandler.MediaPlayerStopped:
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
//it use some helper class and 
xml file attached to this 

cordova plugin 
package cordova.plugin.VLCPlugin;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.mindtree.gladiuscms.R;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import cordova.plugin.VLCPlugin.util.UrlProvider;

public class VLCPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
   UrlProvider urlProvider = new UrlProvider();
    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {

        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) webView.getView().getParent();



    }


    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if(action.equals("play")) {
            String url = args.getString(0);

            UrlProvider urlProvide = UrlProvider.getInstance();
            urlProvide.setUrl(url);



         resources.getIdentifier("R.layout.activity_fullscreen_vlc_player",                   "layout", package_name);
            cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Application app = cordova.getActivity().getApplication();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(app, FullscreenVlcPlayer.class);
                    cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                   }
        return false;
    }
}

now i am cslling this plugin from my controller 
window.vlcPlugin.onMediaLoad("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");}

an my html code is 

<div ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="video" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete()"></div>

i want to see video in this div 
<div class="video_player_screen" ng-drop="tru >
```

Comment: please provide some code, you wrote. On top of this, we may be able to help you more easily.

Comment: actually I have a vlc plugin for playing the video in ionic app.
in ionic app i am calling

 window.vlcPlugin.onMediaLoad("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");

i need to play that video in perticular div of my page

 ng-drag-success="onDragComplete(cam.name,cam.id)">

<div class="video_player_screen" ng-drop="true"  >